# Не создается сущность в БД PostgreSQL при работе с моделями Django

Tags: python-3.x, база-данных, django, postgresql, backend

У меня есть простая модель

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

при выполнении команды ниже,все нормально

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

но при подтверждении миграции,ничего не происходит и сущность в БД не создается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код файла settings.py для настройки работы с базой данных

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Comment: Модель к какому приложению относится? Это приложение добавлено в INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev модель относиться в приложению "application",да оно добавлено в INSTALLED_APPS